# Why do we need a interface to define every service in aem?

Tags: service, interface, osgi, aem

I have been working with for a while but somehow never thought about this. Every aem project that I have worked on, has one similarity in their code structure. There is an interface for every service written.

My question is why do we need a interface for every service?

Can `@reference` or `@inject` not use the services without an interface?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using interfaces is a good practice to decouple the user of a service from the implementation. In many cases you even want to have an API bundle so the user of the service does not need a maven dependency to the implementing bundle.

On the other hand you are not required to use interfaces. Especially when I wire components inside a bundle interfaces are often an unnecessary layer. In this case simply export the service directly with the class.

See [here for an example](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-distribution-journal/blob/f93304d289d49ccc82f07c5b8f0ba2c82a379dc8/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/distribution/journal/impl/shared/DistributionMetricsService.java#L35-L36):

```
@Component(service = DistributionMetricsService.class)
public class DistributionMetricsService {
...
}
```

and [here for the client code](https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-distribution-journal/blob/f93304d289d49ccc82f07c5b8f0ba2c82a379dc8/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/distribution/journal/impl/subscriber/DistributionSubscriber.java#L162-L163):

```
@Reference
private DistributionMetricsService distributionMetricsService;
```

So the main difference is that you have to specify the `service` property if you want to export a component with its implementation class.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "API bundle so user does not need a maven dependency"? How does the API bundle encapsulate the implementation and original service?

2. In my understanding, the service property will always hold the value of component class. Then is it not redundant to specify it? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you publish your service with an interface then the user of the service just references the interface. If you then put the interface into an API bundle to separate it from the implementation then the user of the service only needs to depend on the API bundle in maven. This is a good practice to decouple the user and provider of a service.